# I believe this algorithm is O(N). Am I correct?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, computer-science

This algorithm reverses an array of N integers. I believe this algorithm is O(N) because for each loop iteration, the four lines of code are executed once thus completing the job in 4N time.

```
public static void reverseTheNumbers(int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length / 2; i++) {
        int j = list.length - 1 - i;
        int temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "competing the job in 4N time", but it is indeed O(N).

Comment: My understanding is that in big O notation you measure algorithm complexity in terms of input and output. In this case your input is an array of N numbers, but the output is also a an array of N elements (since void as doesn't return anything I am not sure if this is correct). But from that assumption the complexity would be O(1)

Comment: @manuelmourato the output type has nothing to do with whether the algorithm is O(N).

Comment: @manuelmourato no, algorithmic complexity does not shrink when the algorithm returns `void`.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't such a thing as 4N time. The algorithm is linear because as you increase the size of the input the runtime of the algorithm increases proportionally. In other words if you doubled the size of `list` you would expect the algorithm to take twice as long.

It doesn't matter how many operations you do inside your loop - as long as they are each constant time (relative to the input) the runtime of the loop is determined simply by the number of iterations.

Put another way, these four statements are - all together - an O(1) operation.

```
int j = list.length - 1 - i;
int temp = list[i];
list[i] = list[j];
list[j] = temp;
```

There's nothing significant about the fact that this sequence of steps is expressed in four statements in Java syntax - experimenting with `javap` suggests these four lines compiles into ~20 bytecode commands, and who knows how many processor instructions that bytecode gets converted into. The good news is Big-O notation works the same regardless of the particular syntax - a sequence of operations is O(1) or constant time if its execution time is the same regardless of the input.

Therefore you're doing an O(1) operation N times; aka O(N).

Comment: Correct, I meant to say each statement would execute 4N times.

Comment: That's still asymptotically O(n) - constant multipliers like 4 don't affect the runtime of an algorithm *relative to the input*.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are correct. The number of operations is linearly dependent on the size of the array (N), making it an O(N) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the complexity of the algorithm is O(n). 
However, the exact "time" (because there are no constant factors in asymptotic complexity, check comment below) is not 4 times the size of the array, we could say it is 1/2*(c1+c2+c3+c3) times the size of the array, where 1/2 corresponds to each loop iteration and each c corresponds to the time needed for each operation inside theloop. 
It would be 4 times the size of the array, if the algorithm was iterating the whole array 4 times.

Comment: "*It would be 4N, if the algorithm was iterating the whole array 4 times.*" - no, iterating over a list four times is still O(n). There are no constant factors when discussing asymptotic complexity.

Comment: That's correct, it was a typo on my side. Even if time needed is 4N, the asymptotic complexity will still be O(N). Replaced complexity with "time" to avoid misinterpretation. Hope it helps.

Comment: You're still using "4N", which at best is confusing since it's still in terms of N. You could say "4x" or "four times as long" if you're not talking about the asymptotic complexity.